# Adding an event listener to the title of a dialog box

Tags: android, dialog

I have a custom dialog box and i would like to add on an on touch listener to the title if possible.

I am able to set the title with custom text but i am unsure how to retrieve the title in order to accomplish this.

Is this possible? The only demonstrable code i have so far is the code that creates and set the title of the dialog.

```
   //Creating and setting the title of the dialog
   final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(activity);
   dialog.setTitle(title);
```

Comment: Dialog as in DialogFragment or AlertDialog?

Comment: I have just realized i am using the Dialog base class directly and not one of it's sub classes - maybe that is the problem?

Comment: Can you post that code? It's hard to tell without seeing your code.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this possible?

**Yes,**

> How?

- Add custom view for title of dialog.
- Set dialogInterface.OnClickListener to the view you have added as title view.
- Do what you want in the onClick of it.